# How to restrict user to edit calendar manually in android

Tags: java, android, calendar

How can we restrict user from editing date-picker calendar manually?
On clicking calendar open ups and then user long press on year part and edit it and make some other year.But date picker instance take its own year which should be there on scrolling not editing .Please check image. it will be more clear. 
Thanks

Comment: This is not how you ask question. follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can set a pop up alert dialog, which can restrict a user to chage the date if he/she wants to change. 
or you can create your static time picker and print it on a text view. not editable.